# What is the difference between a delegate type and eventhandler type?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Three related idioms: event, delegate, event-handler. I always get confused by who is "added" to who.

```
event += handler
event += delegate
handler += delegate
```

From what I know:

- delegate: a pointer to a function with a known signature.
- event-handler: a delegate which is registered to an event. Basically, is it the same as a delegate?
- event: a list of delegates\event-handlers which are executed when the event is invoked using event()

What confuses me more is this signature in MSDN:

```
public delegate void EventHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, events are "just" specialized delegates with multiple targets. Don't have the C# spec handy to look it up though.

Comment: @Michael: I second your opinion. An `EventHander` is just a delegate like `Action`, `TimerCallback` and many others. The difference lies in the `MulticastDelegate` used to dispatch events to many event handling delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my summary (please correct me if I'm wrong):

- `delegate` is a pointer to a method (instance\static)
- `eventHandler` is a delegate with a specific signature (sender, eventArgs)
- `event` is an abstraction of accessing a delegate of any type, but it's usually an `eventHandler` by convention

  ```
  //We declare delegates as a new type outside of any class scope (can be also inside?)

      public delegate retType TypeName (params...)

  //Here we assign

      public TypeName concreteDeleagteName = new TypeName (specificMethodName);

  //Declaring event
  //a. taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923952/explicit-event-add-remove-misunderstood

  private EventHandler _explicitEvent;
  public event EventHandler ExplicitEvent
  {
     add
     {
         if (_explicitEvent == null) timer.Start();
         _explicitEvent += value;
     }
     remove
     {
        _explicitEvent -= value;
        if (_explicitEvent == null) timer.Stop();
     }
  }

  //or: b.auto event - the compiler creates a "hidden" delegate which is bounded to this event
        public event TypeName eventName;
  ```

I want to recommend the great article *[Event Handling in .NET Using C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/2137/event-handling-in-net-using-c/3/)*.

So we can only attach (eventName):

```
eventName += new TypeName (specificMethodName);
```

Which is equivalent to (_eventName is a delegate\eventHandler):

```
_eventName += new TypeName (specificMethodName);
```

Answer (score 5):

The event has a `delegate` added to it which "points" to a handler.

So basically, when the `event` is raised, the collection of delegates it has, will be invoked, which as result will invoke handlers connected to those delegates.

```
//declare delegate
public delegate void EventHandler(  Object sender,  EventArgs e)

//create event based on delegate
public event EventHandler evHandler;

//function to attach to handler
public static void Handler(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

attach eventhandler function through delegate to event.
event += new EventHandler(Handler);
```

Answer (score 5):

An "event" is really just shortcut for two methods that work with a delegate - the [add and remove accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx).  The compiler, by default, makes a delegate behind the event (if you don't write your own accessors).

When you call `someEvent += aDelegate;`, you're calling the event's `add` accessor.  Normally, this is translated by the compiler into a `delegate +=` call for a delegate with the same signature as the event - similar to how automatic properties automatically map to a backing field.  This is why an event seems so similar to a delegate.

> what confuses me more is this signature in MSDN:
>   public delegate void EventHandler(  Object sender,  EventArgs e)

This signature is just a delegate signature.  An event can, technically, use any delegate.  However, by convention, it will always take two parameters - the first is the "sender" that raised the event, the second is a class that derives from `EventArgs` (like `EventHandler` and `EventHandler<T>`).