# Get Base Class Event Delegates by Reflection

Tags: c#, inheritance, events, reflection

I need to get all Delegates which are subscribed to events in an object. The object is instantiated from a class which inherits a base class. I can get all Delegates for events defined in the class, but not for the ones of the base class.

So, in code, here's what I have in principle (I don't copy declarations, value aggregations and returns etc. to keep it short):

```
public class DerivedClass : Base Class
{
    public event EventHandler<UserDefinedEventArgs> DerivedClassEvent;         
}
```

The Base class is defined like this (hosting the functions for getting the Delegates I need):

```
public abstract class BaseClass 
{
    public event EventHandler<UserDefinedEventArgs> BaseClassEvent;

    public Dictionary<EventInfo, List<Delegate>> getAllEventsSubscribersList()
    {

        EventInfo[] eventInfoS = this.GetType().GetEvents(); //Get all events / event infos defined in the class

        foreach (EventInfo eventInfo in eventInfoS)
        {
            resDelegates = this.getEventSubscriberList(eventInfo); //Get the delegates for each event
        }
    }

    public List<Delegate> getEventSubscriberList(EventInfo eventInfo)
    {
        FieldInfo eventFieldInfo = this.GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

        Delegate eventFieldValue = (System.Delegate)eventFieldInfo.GetValue(this);

        Delegate[] subscribedDelegates = eventFieldValue.GetInvocationList();
    }
}
```

Then, I try to get all events and their Delegates like this:

```
DerivedClass myObject = new DerivedClass();
Dictionary<EventInfo, List<Delegate>> EventAndDelegatesList = myObject.getAllEventsSubscribersList();
```

When calling 'getAllEventsSubscribersList', all events of the derived as well as of the base class are found correctly. 
But in the function for retreiving the actual Delegates, the FieldInfo for the 'BaseClassEvent' is always 'null'.

How can I read the delegates for the base class event?

Comment: ok, partially figured it out: When getting the FieldInfo with  `this.GetType().BaseType.GetField(...)` in the specific case I get the Info and then the delegates. No generic solution though...

Comment: Use BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy

Answer (score 0):

An event is like an auto-implemented property for a delegate. You can also declare it explicitly. This would allow you to insert the event handler in a collection of your choice

```
public event EventHandler<UserDefinedEventArgs> DerivedClassEvent
{
    add
    {
        // TODO: add the event handler to a collection and subscribe it to a hidden delegate.
    }
    remove
    {
        // TODO: remove the event handler from the collection and unsubscribe it.
    }
}
```

See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2923974/880990
- [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-implement-custom-event-accessors)

Comment: Good to know! Thanks, will think that through, seems helpful.